# How to prevent Google Apps Script from changing existing strings (Date, Duration etc.) to time stamps in Google Sheets

Tags: string, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp

I am trying to replace employee IDs with employee names in the google sheets using the below script. FYI, the sheet also has other columns including dates and durations etc.

```
function runReplaceInSheet(){
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
 var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();   
 replaceInSheet(values, 'SR1193CS', 'Shyam Reganti');
 sheet.getDataRange().setValues(values);
```

}

```
function replaceInSheet(values, to_replace, replace_with) {
 for(var row in values){
 var replaced_values = values[row].map(function(original_value) {
 return original_value.toString().replace(to_replace,replace_with);
});
 values[row] = replaced_values;
```

}
}

I was able to run the script successfully. However, the dates and durations in the google sheet are converted to time stamps after running the script. **I want to prevent that from happening** as those fields are used for reporting purposes and is new format is disrupting the reports. For example the existing duration in the sheet "00:37:00" is converted to "Sat Dec 30 1899 00:37:00 GMT-0600 (Central Standard Time)" after running the script.

Please help me and let me know if there is a work around for this.
P.S. I am not a coder.

Comment: Try to specify the range like - `var values = sheet.getRange("B2:C100").getValues();`

Comment: Perfect, it worked. Thank you so much. I appreciate you help.